# Facebook share button WCAG issue

Tags: facebook, user-interface, facebook-javascript-sdk, accessibility

#### Issue description:

When the user uses keyboard key -'TAB', to get through the site, he stucks on into generated Facebook button iframe (which is taken from [Facebook Developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#configurator) - Share Button Configurator section), also the same issue is on generated example.

#### How to reproduce?

1. Go to [button generator section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#configurator)
2. Set active **'URL to share'** section`s input
3. Then press **TAB** key on your keyboard
4. and try to get on **'Get code'** button (with **TAB** key).

This is issue fits [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/G21?fbclid=IwAR1eOH4t-4bNFlN4_DqEIRZtbJdmT9Sr31Q7C_We-H_1Emq5EtpIyxQxNiA#G21-examples) - G21: Ensuring that users are not trapped in content

#### What I have tried:

[Like button generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) - here **TAB** key is working fine and the user can get through the content (definitely through generated buttons iframe).

Also, [Save button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/save) works fine.

#### Expectation:

The user can navigate through the site with **TAB** key and is not trapped in the iframe.

Regards, Reinis.

Comment: This hardly seems to be a question fit for this site, let alone anything people here could do anything about in the first place. You should perhaps rather file a bug report with Facebook for this issue, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I did create [a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/371834346995775), but I received a rejection. Off course, in the given answer are links, but after all, in all sites advise write a bug report in that site. I hoped, here we`ll be people who could help with this issue.

Comment: There is no way to influence the styling or behavior of these iframes from the outside, other than the configuration options Facebook offers. I agree with what you said in the bug report, that it is their issue and they should fix it - but if they refuse, little anyone else can do.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. So, I will wait and hope, that in someday they will fix that issue. :D

Comment: Hi Reinis. Do you actually have a requirement to show the current number of likes, or which friends liked the same thing? If not, it would be an option to just do the button yourself and link to facebook – this would also avoid privacy issues

Comment: Thanks for an advice Andy, but, yes, I have a requirement to show the number.